# How do I prevent a long overflow?

Tags: java, long-integer, biginteger

My assignment ask us to ask the user to enter a number and print the factorial of it,

it also ask us to not allow the user to chose any negative number or number over 25, when they do, we loop them back to scanner to re renter a number

we were also told to store the number in a long, but when I do, if the user enters a number over 20 and =<25, the answer becomes a negative causing a long overflow.

I tried changing the long to BigInteger, but when I keep getting an error on ever line i use BigInteger instead of long

```
boolean correctInputn= false;
    
    while(!correctInputn)
    {
    long number;// declares variables for storing number
    long factorial = 1;// declare variable for storing factorial
    

    System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 25"); // tells user to enter number
    number = scanner.nextLong();
    
         if (number <0)  
            {System.out.println("Positive numbers only");// if number entered is negative
             correctInputn = false; continue;} // if user enters number less than 0 loops back to code start
       
       
         else if (number > 25)
             { System.out.println("Number to large to print");
               correctInputn = false; continue;} // if user enters number over 25 loops back to code start
        
    
          else  {
      // if user enter 10, counter starts at 10 and runs to two
        for(long mynumber = number; mynumber >= 1; mynumber--) {
            factorial = factorial*mynumber; // mynumber would contain different values and that is multiplied by value present in factorial value and stored again in factorial variable
        }
    
    System.out.println("The factorial of " + number +" is equal to " + factorial);
    break;
    }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot prevent an overflow of a `long`, BigInteger is the answer, please post your code using it. For BigInteger, you have use the `multiply` method instead of the `*` operator.

Comment: And when you post your code using `BigInteger`, please indent it properly. It helps readability more than you think for someone who didn’t write the code. Your IDE can do it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BigInteger` is a reference type - like all types in java except the hardcoded list of `long`, `int`, `double`, `short`, `float`, `char`, `byte`, and `boolean`. You can invoke methods on it. The `+` can be used if the thing on its left's type is a `String` which will invoke `toString()` on them and concatenate them. That's it. They do not 'support' -, +, *, etcetera. Instead, they have the methods `.multiply` and `.add` and friends. Note that this doesn't add a number to the object, it calculates the value and returns it, e.g. you'd write `factorial = factorial.multiply(myNumber)`. You'll have to replace **all** operators with the appropriate method, and you'll have to turn **all** numbers in `BigInteger` objects, using `BigInteger.valueOf(20)` for example.

You can't magically prevent longs from overflowing. It's a fundamental aspect of math on 64-bit numbers: You can't store more than 2^64 different things in 64-bits for the same reason 1+1=2 - because of fundamental mathematical reasons.

Comment: That’s helpful, detailed and precise without any spoon-feeding. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

```
**I FOUND A SOLUTION AND NOW IT DOESNT OVERFLOW**
**MAIN**
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Factorial factNum;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean flagCheck = false;

        System.out.println("Please give a number between 0 - 25: ");
        factNum = new Factorial(in.nextLong());

        //check if the number is in the limits
        while(!flagCheck) {

            if (factNum.getVarForFact() < 0){
                System.out.println("Number must be over 0. Please enter again a 
                number between 0-25");
                factNum = new Factorial(in.nextLong());
            } else if (factNum.getVarForFact() > 25){
                System.out.println("Number must be under 25. Please enter again a 
                number between 0-25");
                factNum = new Factorial(in.nextLong());
            } else if (factNum.getVarForFact() == 0) {
                factNum.setFinalFact(1);
                System.out.println("The factorial of " + factNum.getVarForFact() + " 
                is " + factNum.getFinalFact());
                flagCheck = true;
            } else{
                factNum.factorial();
                System.out.println("The factorial of " + factNum.getVarForFact() + " 
                 is " + factNum.getFactorial());
                flagCheck = true;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**FACTORIAL CLASS**

```
    import java.math.BigInteger;

    class Factorial {
    //variable for storing the given number and find the factorial
    private long varForFact;
    private long finalFact;

    private BigInteger factorial = BigInteger.ONE;
    //Constructor
    Factorial(long varForFact){
        this.varForFact = varForFact;
    }

    //Getter
    public long getVarForFact(){
        return this.varForFact;
    }

    public long getFinalFact() {
        return finalFact;
    }

    public BigInteger getFactorial() {
        return factorial;
    }

    //Setter
    public void setVarForFact(long varForFact){
         this.varForFact = varForFact;
    }


    public void setFinalFact(long finalFact) {
        this.finalFact = finalFact;
    }

    //factorial method, it will return the factorial
    public void factorial(){

        for (long i = this.varForFact; i > 0; i--) {
            this.factorial = this.factorial.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The down vote did not come from me . It was already there when I saw this answer. I was surprised and cannot explain it. Perhaps someone else didn't like the fact that you posted a second answer, but I still don't see that warranting a down vote.